# How to take a substring from the beginning of a string up to the last occurrence of a character that is before a specific index in the string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, substring

The title might be confusing. Just say I have a newspaper article. I want to cut it off around a certain point, say 4096 characters, but not in the middle of a word, rather before the last word that takes the length over 4096. Here is a short example:

```
"This is the entire article."
```

If I want to cut it off before a word that takes the total length over 16 characters, here is the result I would want:

```
"This is the entire article.".function
=> "This is the"
```

The word "entire" takes the total length over 16, so it must be removed, along with all characters after it, and the space before it.

Here is what I don't want:

```
"This is the entire article."[0,15]
=> "This is the ent"
```

It looks easy in writing, but I don't know how to put it into programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this for your example:

```
sentence = "This is the entire article."
length_limit = 16
last_space = sentence.rindex(' ', length_limit) # => 11
shortened_sentence = sentence[0...last_space]   # => "This is the"
```

Answer (score 1):

While the answer of marco is correct for a plain ruby, there is a simpler variant if you happen to use rails, as it already includes a [truncate helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) (which in turn uses the [truncate method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-truncate) added to the String class by ActiveSupport):

```
text = "This is the entire article."
truncate(text, :length => 16, :separator => ' ')
# or equivalently
text.truncate(16, :separator => ' ')
```